# How to Style React-Icons

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

I am trying to figure out how to style icons that I import using [`react-icons`](https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/).

In particular, I would like to be able to create a look similar to this:  [image]

That is to say, I'd like to add a background color, padding, border-radius, etc.  However, I can't find an easy way to do that.

I can add a size and color prop and that will change the actual size and color of the icon.  But there is no easy way for me to change the other elements.

Does anyone know how I can do this (or can they recommend a different library that can help me with this)?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use `IconContext` as mentioned in the [Docs](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons#configuration).

```js
function BlueLargeIcon() {
  return (
    <IconContext.Provider
      value={{ color: 'blue', size: '50px' }}
    >
      <div>
        <FaBeer />
      </div>
    </IconContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

[image]

To target specific Icon Components, you can use the `style` prop or use the same API (see [Configurations](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons#configuration)) on the component itself:

```
const style = { color: "white", fontSize: "1.5em" }
<FaFacebookF style={style} />

// API
<FaFacebookF color="white" fontSize="1.5em" />
```

Comment: I am  using FaExclamationTriangle in my react component I want to customize it so that can look like black border triangle with black exclamation and yellow color filled inside triangle.
When I am applying yellow color css to icon it show yellow triangle with while exclamation .

Answer (score 36):

Colours of some icons can't be changed. For example, I tried to change the colour of `{ GrClose }` icon by doing this:

```
<GrClose
    className="icon"
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '20px',
      right: '20px',
    }}
    size="50px"
    color="white"
    onClick={handleExit}
/>
```

It just didn't change, but when I replaced my icon with `{ AiOutlineClose }` icon it worked!

Comment: You rock Uttkarsh, so much time lost trying everything, and you are right, some icons just can't be styled, unless you target them this way as I was doing:  svg path {
  fill: "red";
 }
 
 svg {
  font-size: 2rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: the inconsistency of icons inheriting colors is really silly to me. I'm sure it's because some svgs use fill while others use stroke so there isn't a way to consistently apply colors, but it definitely causes issues that aren't addressed as far as I've seen in the repo.

Answer (score 12):

I think the easiest way here would be to just pass the `className` prop directly to the Icon you'd like to apply styles to. [Source Code in a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-haze-rhvyp?file=/src/App.js). I've used [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/) classes here, but you could use your own just as easily.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  FaFacebookF,
  FaTwitter,
  FaInstagram,
  FaPinterest
} from "react-icons/fa";

export default function App() {
  let circleClasses = "inline-block p-7 rounded-full w-20 mx-auto";
  let iconStyles = { color: "white", fontSize: "1.5em" };
  return (
    <div className="App grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-4 gap-2 w-3/4 mx-auto">
      <h1 className="col-span-full">Icon Demo</h1>
      <span style={{ background: "#3B5998" }} className={circleClasses}>
        <FaFacebookF style={iconStyles} />
      </span>
      <span style={{ background: "#1DA1F2" }} className={circleClasses}>
        <FaTwitter style={iconStyles} />
      </span>
      <span style={{ background: "black" }} className={circleClasses}>
        <FaInstagram style={iconStyles} />
      </span>
      <span style={{ background: "#BD081C" }} className={circleClasses}>
        <FaPinterest style={iconStyles} />
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you'd like a little more context as to how this works, we can take a dive into the source code for react-icons.
If you take a look at [where the IconContext is defined](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/blob/master/packages/react-icons/src/iconContext.tsx) within react-icons, you can see the allowed props:

```
export interface IconContext {
  color?: string;
  size?: string;
  className?: string;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  attr?: React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>;
}

export const DefaultContext: IconContext = {
  color: undefined,
  size: undefined,
  className: undefined,
  style: undefined,
  attr: undefined,
};

export const IconContext: React.Context<IconContext> = React.createContext && React.createContext(DefaultContext);
```

Indeed, you're able to pass in color, size, style, additional svg attributes, and even a className string. But, this requires that you wrap the Icon component in the context.

When you install react-icons, all of the icons are added into the node_modules directory in a format that looks like this:

```js
// THIS FILE IS AUTO GENERATED
var GenIcon = require('../lib').GenIcon
module.exports.Fa500Px = function Fa500Px (props) {
  return GenIcon({"tag":"svg","attr":{"viewBox":"0 0 448 512"},"child":[{"tag":"path","attr":{"d":"M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7 8.5-28.6 53 0 89.4-10.1 89.4-64.4 0-61-77.1-89.6-116.9-44.6-23.5 26.4-17.6 42.1-17.6 157.6 50.7 31 118.3 22 160.4-20.1 24.8-24.8 38.5-58 38.5-93 0-35.2-13.8-68.2-38.8-93.3-24.8-24.8-57.8-38.5-93.3-38.5s-68.8 13.8-93.5 38.5c-.3.3-16 16.5-21.2 23.9l-.5.6c-3.3 4.7-6.3 9.1-20.1 6.1-6.9-1.7-14.3-5.8-14.3-11.8V20c0-5 3.9-10.5 10.5-10.5h241.3c8.3 0 8.3 11.6 8.3 15.1 0 3.9 0 15.1-8.3 15.1H130.3v132.9h.3c104.2-109.8 282.8-36 282.8 108.9 0 178.1-244.8 220.3-310.1 62.8zm63.3-260.8c-.5 4.2 4.6 24.5 14.6 20.6C306 56.6 384 144.5 390.6 144.5c4.8 0 22.8-15.3 14.3-22.8-93.2-89-234.5-57-238.3-38.2zM393 414.7C283 524.6 94 475.5 61 310.5c0-12.2-30.4-7.4-28.9 3.3 24 173.4 246 256.9 381.6 121.3 6.9-7.8-12.6-28.4-20.7-20.4zM213.6 306.6c0 4 4.3 7.3 5.5 8.5 3 3 6.1 4.4 8.5 4.4 3.8 0 2.6.2 22.3-19.5 19.6 19.3 19.1 19.5 22.3 19.5 5.4 0 18.5-10.4 10.7-18.2L265.6 284l18.2-18.2c6.3-6.8-10.1-21.8-16.2-15.7L249.7 268c-18.6-18.8-18.4-19.5-21.5-19.5-5 0-18 11.7-12.4 17.3L234 284c-18.1 17.9-20.4 19.2-20.4 22.6z"}}]})(props);
};
```

If we take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/blob/master/packages/react-icons/src/iconBase.tsx) for `GenIcon` we can get a bit more context for how this is working.

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { IconContext, DefaultContext } from './iconContext';

export interface IconTree {
  tag: string;
  attr: {[key: string]: string};
  child: IconTree[];
}


function Tree2Element(tree: IconTree[]): React.ReactElement<{}>[] {
  return tree && tree.map((node, i) => React.createElement(node.tag, {key: i, ...node.attr}, Tree2Element(node.child)));
}
export function GenIcon(data: IconTree) {
  return (props: IconBaseProps) => (
    <IconBase attr={{...data.attr}} {...props}>
      {Tree2Element(data.child)}
    </IconBase>
  );
}

export interface IconBaseProps extends React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement> {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  size?: string | number;
  color?: string;
  title?: string;
}

export type IconType = (props: IconBaseProps) => JSX.Element;
export function IconBase(props:IconBaseProps & { attr?: {} }): JSX.Element {
  const elem = (conf: IconContext) => {
    const {attr, size, title, ...svgProps} = props;
    const computedSize = size || conf.size || "1em";
    let className;
    if (conf.className) className = conf.className;
    if (props.className) className = (className ? className + ' ' : '') + props.className;

    return (
      <svg
        stroke="currentColor"
        fill="currentColor"
        strokeWidth="0"
        {...conf.attr}
        {...attr}
        {...svgProps}
        className={className}
        style={{ color: props.color || conf.color, ...conf.style, ...props.style}}
        height={computedSize}
        width={computedSize}
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
      {title && <title>{title}</title>}
      {props.children}
    </svg>
    )
  };

  return IconContext !== undefined
    ? <IconContext.Consumer>{(conf: IconContext) => elem(conf)}</IconContext.Consumer>
    : elem(DefaultContext);
}
```

So, `GenIcon` is a function that accepts an object with an interface of IconTree which includes `tag`, `attr` and `child` properties. We can see this in action in the generated code above. `GenIcon` returns a function itself. This function accepts props as an argument which implements the `IconBaseProps` interface. The `IconBaseProps` interface extends `React.SVGAttributes` which include [`className`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname) and [`style`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style). Those are then passed as props to the `IconBase` component here:

```js
export function GenIcon(data: IconTree) {
  return (props: IconBaseProps) => (
    <IconBase attr={{...data.attr}} {...props}>
      {Tree2Element(data.child)}
    </IconBase>
  );
}
```

To get a sense of how `IconBase` actually works with respect to the `IconContext` let's check out its return statement:

```js
    return IconContext !== undefined
    ? <IconContext.Consumer>{(conf: IconContext) => elem(conf)}</IconContext.Consumer>
    : elem(DefaultContext);
```

Here, we can see that `IconBase` will invoke a function called `elem` (defined inside the body of `IconBase`) either way. So, `IconBase` will use the `IconContext` if one is defined, wrapping the returned element in `IconContext.Consumer` and calling `elem` with the `IconContext`. But, if `IconContext` is not defined in this scope, `IconBase` will use the `DefaultContext` instead.

To understand how this is working, we need to look at the `elem` function defined inside of `IconBase`. Here's the full source again:

```js
  const elem = (conf: IconContext) => {
    const {attr, size, title, ...svgProps} = props;
    const computedSize = size || conf.size || "1em";
    let className;
    if (conf.className) className = conf.className;
    if (props.className) className = (className ? className + ' ' : '') + props.className;

    return (
      <svg
        stroke="currentColor"
        fill="currentColor"
        strokeWidth="0"
        {...conf.attr}
        {...attr}
        {...svgProps}
        className={className}
        style={{ color: props.color || conf.color, ...conf.style, ...props.style}}
        height={computedSize}
        width={computedSize}
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
      {title && <title>{title}</title>}
      {props.children}
    </svg>
    )
  };
```

So, if you take a look at the code relating to className, you can see that we can actually add className to the Context and/or the props directly (`<FaFacebook className="bg-blue" />`) and they'll actually be combined and applied to the returned `svg`

```js
    let className;
    if (conf.className) className = conf.className;
    if (props.className) className = (className ? className + ' ' : '') + props.className;
```

Also, the styles defined in either the Context or the props will be combined and applied to the svg

```js
 style={{ color: props.color || conf.color, ...conf.style, ...props.style}}
```

One thing to note here is that all of the styles and classes are being applied directly to the returned `svg` element. So, in your case, you'd probably need to have a wrapping element to build out the border-radius and background color and then apply the relevant styles for color and size directly to the svg.

Answer (score 6):

Simply add a `color` attribute to the icon tag. The value can be any CSS color.

```
<Icon color="blue" />
```

Note that some icons can't be colored due to their SVG characteristics. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67216972/1264804).

Answer (score 3):

```
import {IconContext} from "react-icons";

class App extends component {

return (

<div>
<IconContext.Provider value={{ className="myReact-icons"}}>
       <FaBeer />
  </IconContext.Provider>
</div>
);  
}

css example below

.myreact-icons { color: red;
                 height: 40px;
               }
```

Comment: This won't compile as is. You must change "className=" to "className:". Also, I tried this and my icon is still black.

Comment: @BrianLegg the css class needs to be changed accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by simply adding `color` property to icon. The same goes for other properties like `size`. The color value can be any CSS color.

```
<BiXCircle size={40} color="red" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select everything inside the SVG icon with `.icon > *` and use the CSS `fill` property to fill the SVG path.

```
.icon > * {
    fill: #B3B3B3;
}

.icon > *:hover {
    fill: #747474;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Color changes on Grommet Icons don't apply. You can try with others either by passing a class `<IconExample class="my-icon" />` and target it with CSS or directly inside `<IconExample color={'blue'} />`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<HiOutlineInformationCircle
size= {40}
color="#777C92"
className = "m-1 cursor-pointer hover: stroke-[#E5765D]"
/>
```

Comment: This does not look *an easy way to add a background padding, border-radius, etc.*.

Comment: hover has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your icon element in a span element:

```
<div className="social-icons">
  <span>
    <FaGithub/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Then style it using CSS:

```
.social-icons span{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;          
    color: var(--grey);        
}
         
.social-icons span:hover{
    color:black
}
```

Comment: Extra markup isn't necessary or advisable.

Answer (score 0):

You can export them as an object(s) with other properties and map through them.

```js
import { FaInstagram, FaTwitter } from 'react-icons/fa';

export const socialIcons = [
    {
        icon: <FaInstagram
            style={{ height: '30px', width: '30px' }}
        />,
        title: 'Instagram',
        link: '',
        color: '#C13584',
        isOpen: false,
        id: 'instagram',
    },
    {
        icon: <FaTwitter
        style={{ height: '30px', width: '30px' }}/>,
        title: 'Twitter',
        link: '',
        color: '#00acee',
        isOpen: false,
        id: 'twitter',
    },
];
```

---

```js
import { socialIcons } from '../';

// ...
        <div>
            {socialIcons.map((social) => (
                <div>
                    <a href={social.link}>
                        <button style={{ color: social.color }}
                        id={social.id}>
                            {social.icon}
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

icons are usually SVGs elements. To change the color of an SVG element you can use properties such as "fill", "stroke" or "filter". this will change the background or color of the icon. to style an icon u can use the `className` attribute on the icon.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function blackReactIcons () {
     return(
             <div>
                 <FaTwitter fill='#000' />
                 <FaLinkedinIn fill='#000' />
                 <FaGithub fill='#000' />
             </div>

        );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

In your styles.scss or css

```css
.iconFaFacebook {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<FaFacebook className={styles.iconFaFacebook} />
```

Comment: i tried but it does not work