# css can't override react icon color

Tags: css, selector, react-icons

A simple illustration of my problem

```
import {BsFillArrowRightCircleFill} from "react-icons/bs";

export default function Icon(){
    return <BsFillArrowRightCircleFill className='icon'/>;
}
```

In the CSS file, if I put

```
.icon {
   color: red;
}
```

it would work fine. But if I add a global style like this

```
* {
   color: yellow;
}
.icon {
   color: red;
}
```

then the color would stay yellow. I can't figure out why this selector doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try ```:global(.yourclass) {}```?

Answer (score 1):

Try Using the selector as:

```
    .icon{
          *{
             color: red;
           }
        }
```

Also visit this link and you'll learn more about it. [How to Style React-Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636280/how-to-style-react-icons)